# Diophantine equation: $n^2=c(4ab-a-b)-b$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, diophantine-equations

Let $n$ be a positive integer. The Diophantine equation 
$$
n^2=c(4ab-a-b)-b,\qquad (a,b,c\in\mathbb{Z}^+)
$$
is solvable for $n\equiv\pm1\pmod3$, but I stuck for $n\equiv0\pmod3$.

Is there any method to solve it?

thanks!

P.S. The method I used for the cases $n\equiv\pm1\pmod3$ is as follows:
$$
n^2+b=c(4ab-a-b)
$$
Assume for a moment the left-hand side is prime. Since $4ab-a-b>1$ for all $a,b>0$, therefore $c=1$. Now let $n=3k\pm1$ then 
$$
n^2=9k^2\pm6k+1=3(3k^2\pm2k+1)-2=(4ab-a-b)-b=(4b-1)a-2b
$$
If we let $b=1$, we have $a=3k^2\pm2k+1$.

Comment: Can you show your progress? What is your proof if $n\equiv\pm1\pmod{3}$? And do you want to find *all* solutions, or just *a* solution for each $n$?

Comment: @Servaes, I added in the text.

Comment: @Servaes,  For your second question I need to show that for a given positive integer $n$ there is (?) (at least one) solution in positive integers $a,b,c$.

Comment: So you've found that putting $b=c=1$ gives $n^2=3a-2$ which is solvable for any $n\equiv 1,2 \mod 3$. You could instead put $a=b=1$ giving $n^2=2c-1$, which is solvable for all odd $n$. This leaves only $n\equiv 0 \mod 6$ still to be done.

Comment: Now posts also on MO: [Diophantine equation: $n^2=c(4ab-a-b)-b$?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/336352) (It is recommended to [linke the copies to each other](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5085/moderator-supported-official-guidelines-for-legitimate-crossposting/5088#5088) when [meta-tag:cross-posting].)